# Excel subtract 2 timestamps only if they have a related parameter

Tags: excel, excel-formula, nested

I have a table that looks something like:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Batch 1 | Date/Time | 1 |
| Batch 1 | Date/Time | 2 |
| Batch 1 | Date/Time | 3 |
| Batch 1 | Date/Time | 4 |
| Batch 2 | Date/Time | 1 |
| Batch 2 | Date/Time | 2 |
| Batch 2 | Date/Time | 3 |
| Batch 2 | Date/Time | 4 |

I want to find the time difference between Column C entries '4' and '1' but only if they share the same Batch #.

In an added Column D, I have a function that reads =IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(4,C4)),B4-B1,""). It will search Column C for any entries that contain a value of '4'. If TRUE, it will subtract the times from that row with the one 3 rows above it that should contain the '1' for the same batch. If FALSE, leave the cell blank. It works fine if the list is perfect but there can be instances where there may be multiple '2' or '3' values for a given Batch # so that breaks the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMIFS to return the correct value:

```
=IF(C2=4,B2-SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,A2,C:C,1),"")
```

[image]

---

If there are multiple `1`s then we can take the earliest date/time by using MINIFS instead.

```
=IF(C2=4,B2-MINIFS(B:B,A:A,A2,C:C,1),"")
```

Comment: This helped a lot, thank you! What if the case is there is multiple '1' entries? Is there a way for the formula to grab say the earliest entry and ignore the others?

Comment: Change the SUMIFS to MINIFS